# Extract json-array for use in SELECT ... IN clause

Tags: arrays, postgresql, jsonb

Not sure what postgresql function should I use to extract an array from a JSONB object and use it later in `select ... in clause`. Preferably as a result set with one integer column.
From the json below I want to extract `types`

```
{
    "data": {
        "types": [
            1,
            2,
            3
        ]
    }
}
```

I've tried the following but it triggers an error:

```
select * from json_array_elements(
select * from jsonb_extract_path_text('
{
    "data": {
        "types": [
            1,
            2,
            3
        ]
    }
}
', 'data', 'types')
);
```

Maybe I'm missing the right syntax/function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL 12+, you could use set-returning [`jsonb_path_query()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#id-1.5.8.22.8.13.2.2.19.1.1.1): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/bbpOZV79)

```sql
select * from test 
where id in (
select jsonb_path_query('{"data": {"types": [1,2,3]}}'::jsonb,
                        '$.data.types[*]')::int);
```

In earlier versions without JSONPath, as [@Diego D suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77328760/extract-json-array-for-use-in-select-in-clause#comment136325471_77328760), you could use [`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE):

```sql
select * from test 
where id in (
select jsonb_array_elements('{"data": {"types": [1,2,3]}}'::jsonb#>'{data,types}')::int);
```

Both `IN`s can also be replaced with an `inner join`. The second solution might fail if a given `jsonb` doesn't have an array at that path. The first one doesn't mind.